# Spring : Configuration of both MVC and WebSocket in one web app

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, spring-websocket

I'm currently working on a Spring web application which makes use of both Spring MVC and Spring Websocket. The configuration is annotation based. I'm using the *AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer* class as initializer, and I am confused about the servlet mappings I should provide, and the way I should do so.

I'd like to have all my MVC controller mapped under "/webservices/" path, and my Websocket endpoint to be under "/websockets/".

Among my *@Configuration* classes, one is dedicated to configure Spring MVC (*@EnableWebMVC*) and another one is dedicated to Spring WebSocket (*@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker*).

I implemented my initializer as follows :

```
@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
   return new Class[] {WebMVCConfiguration.class, WebSocketConfiguration.class};
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
  return new String[]{"/webservices/*","/websockets/*"};
}
```

Also please note that I imported all of my configuration classes through the use of *@Import* on my Root Configuration class. I'm not sure if I should import the MVC and Websocket configuration though, as I already declared them in the getServletConfigClasses() method... But I did.

Anyway, It worked fine this way until now. But I recently added the use of @PropertySource annotation to my app (To inject my app properties through the use of *@Value("${}")* expressions), and thanks to that I noticed that at least the WebSocket Configuration class is ... scanned (?) **twice** : The first time with the @Value field value properly injected, but not the second time (Which caused an error).

While troubleshooting I noticed that I don't have this "double scanning" problem when I remove the WebSocketConfiguration class from the getServletConfigClasses() method : it is scanned only once, with the property valye properly injected. What surprised me is that even without declaring the WebSocketConfiguration in getServletConfigClasses(), the "/websockets" endpoints still works ! My guess is that it is scanned thanks to the *@Import* on my Root config class... but then how Spring knows it should bind the WebSocketConfiguration to the "/websockets" path ?

All of this made me wonder about my understanding of when / how I should import configurations classes. So here are my questions :

1. Do I really need to declare two servlet mappings to keep my services and websockets paths separated as they are ?
2. Is it necessary to declare as much Servlet Config classes as I have Servlet Mappings ? (Seeing how removing the WebSocketConfiguration class from getServletConfigClasses() didn't alter the WebSocket functionality... Or is it just a fluke ?)
3. Will Spring use the same DispatcherServlet for all the Servlet Config classes ? Or will it create one for each mapping I provide ?
4. From what I tried it looks like Spring cannot inject properties through the use of *@Value* in the configuration classes provided thanks to getServletConfigClasses()... It works only when it is imported via *@Import*, or a standard component scanning. Does it seems logical to you ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: 1. No, 2. No, 3. 1. 4. No your understanding on your property resolution works is wrong (properties will only be resolved in the same context as they are loaded in, so if your root loads an `@Propertysource` that is only availabe to bean in that context, NOT by beans in another context, hence the second one fails).

Comment: Thanks for your answer @M.Deinum. So...

Comment: Sorry, comment timeout, I can't edit my previous one... Thanks for your answer @M.Deinum. As for 4., you mean my properties are available to my root context but not in the servlet context created for the websockets, right ? Then I'd just have to add another PropertySource annotation on the associated configuration file and it will be OK, I guess. I'll try this evening !

Comment: Well that solves the symptom however the problem is now that you are basically loading your application twice. Which can hardly be what you want.

Comment: Yes, at least part of it. I think the first thing I should do is remove both WebMVC and WebSocket config files from the imports of my root context, as they will have their own context. Also I just read that beans from the root context are available to underlying contexts (It makes sense : Services are usually declared in root context and accessible from the Controllers in their dedicated servlet context). Too bad it's not the same for properties...